# Доброго времени суток! Прошу помощи с CMake

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cmake, glfw

Я пытаюсь подключить GLFW через CMake в Ubuntu. При компиляции g++ выдает ошибку:

```
/usr/bin/ld: невозможно найти -lGLFW
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/NGL.dir/build.make:85: NGL] Ошибка 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:136: CMakeFiles/NGL.dir/all] Ошибка 2
make: *** [Makefile:130: all] Ошибка 2
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

set(ProjectName NeuralGL)

project(${ProjectName})

add_library(${ProjectName}
    src/Window.cpp
    src/Window.hpp
)

target_link_libraries(${ProjectName} GLFW)
```

Я пробовал подключать, как написано в документации, но ничего не помогло.

Comment: а libglfw3-dev или подобное установлено?

Comment: Да, установлен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я уже сам разобрался, перечитал документацию и переписал CMake файл:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

set(ProjectName NeuralGL)

project(${ProjectName})

add_library(${ProjectName}
    src/Window.cpp
    src/Window.hpp
)

set(GLFW_BUILD_DOCS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(GLFW_BUILD_TESTS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(GLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
add_subdirectory(extends/glfw)
target_link_libraries(${ProjectName} glfw)
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${ProjectName} OpenGL::GL)
```